# What is the significance of different color suits in "Shazam!"?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

When *Billy Batson* makes all his foster friends(*brothers and sisters*) Shazam (gives them the power of Shazam), each of them gets different color suits:

[image: Shazam Family]

*L-R: Pedro Peña (green), Darla Dudley (violet), Eugene Choi (grey), Billy Batson (red), Mary Bromfield (red), Freddy Freeman (blue).*

What is the significance of these different color suits? Does each color represent a different quality or superpower?

Comment: https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a27055443/shazam-ending-marvel-family/ covers the basic history of the multiple Shazams, but not the costume colors.

Comment: @user14111 - Coincidentally, around the time you were a kid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie, but what you're describing reminds me of the alternate Shazam version of Flashpoint. In the Flashpoint world, Shazam (Captain Thunder) is "hosted" by six kids, Billy and fellow foster mates, who each represent one of his powers, as hinted at by [the dialogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO6WL.jpg) and the additional pages of issue #4:

- Eugene: wisdom of Solomon
- Frankie: strength of Hercules
- Billy: courage of Achilles
- Freddie: power of Zeus
- Mary: stamina of Atlas
- Darla: speed of Mercury

[image: Eugene and Frankie character sheets]